# How to retrieve documents from S-RAMP?

Tags: java, jboss, drools, redhat

can someone help me with S-RAMP?
How can I retrieve a .drl document from there with a java application ? Is there some API ? I did search for it but with no success by now. Hope someone here can help me. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @laune hope someone can help me now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution if anyone is interested. There is a client available that offers this functionalities. If anyone is struggling to get data from S-RAMP try this client. See section 7.3.1.

http://docs.jboss.org/overlord/sramp/0.4.0.Final/html/_overlord_s_ramp_implementation.html#_security_authentication